# Anglizismen und Wortschöpfung

Tags: anglicism

Wie kann ich Anglizismen im Deutschen entgehen? Als Beispiel soll *Computer*, *Software* und *Smartphone* genannt werden.

Ich lerne gerne neue Sprachen, spreche mehrere Sprachen fließend und besitze selbst zwei Muttersprachen. Und ich spreche auch gerne Englisch - schreibe auch gerne auf Englisch.

Doch ich empfinde Anstoß daran, englische Wörter im Deutschen zu nutzen. Ich mag solche Wörter im Deutschen nicht. Die Grammatik, Beugungsformen usw. passen eher schlecht als recht ins Deutsche. Sie halten sich auch nicht an Ausspracheregelungen: so wird *Spikes* nicht Schpikes ausgesprochen - wie es sich eigentlich gehöre.

Es klingt so phantasielos. So leidenschaftslos. So als ob jemand kein Deutsch kann, sich deshalb einer anderen Sprache bedienen müsse. Es sieht und klingt einfach scheußlich in meinen Ohren.

Als jemand, der Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, ist es auch ein ungeheurer Graus, englische Wörter mit deutschem Akzent zu hören. Und nicht nur das: oft klingt es in meinen Ohren so, als ob Jemand versuche Englisch zu sprechen - doch dies nicht sonderlich gut kann und deshalb deutsche Wörter nutzen muss. Hoffentlich nimmt hier keiner Anstoß an meiner Offenheit.

Ich finde es schade, dass man im Deutschen nicht eigene Wörter erstellt, wie man es auch im Französischen tut. Als jemand, der freiwillig die deutsche Sprache gelernt hat (und immer noch lernt), finde ich die deutsche Sprache wunderschön. Ich finde, sie ist es Wert, erhalten zu bleiben und geformt zu werden. Deutsch mit gebrochenem Englisch zu kombinieren ist einfach nur ein Graus für meine Ohren.

Im Allgemeinen: wie kann ich am besten Anglizismen entgehen? Oft suche ich nach deutschen Alternativen, doch leider finde ich oft nichts: wo kann ich danach suchen?

Vielen Dank im Voraus.

PS! Ich entschuldige mich für mein schlechtes Deutsch.

Comment: Das Deutsch ist doch ziemlich gut, nichts wofür man sich entschuldigen müsste. "Als jemand die Deutsch lernt" geht aber nicht. Das Geschlecht des Wortes entscheidet, nicht das der Person, welcher Artikel verwendet werden muss, und ich bin *die* Person, *die* Dir das sagen darf. :)

Comment: Und wenn Du Englisch hörst hast Du nicht das Gefühl, da spreche jemand schlecht französisch?

Comment: Wie ist es dann mit dem umgekehrten Prozess, das einführen deutscher Wörter in besipielsweise das Englische? Es gibt zahlreiche Besipiele hierfür: kindergarten, sauerkraut, blitzkrieg, wunderkind, autobahn, bratwurst, ... - Viel Spaß mit einem Haufen amüsanter Lehnwörter auf  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_expressions_in_English), [learn-germn-language-online](http://www.learn-german-language-online.com/german-loanwords.html) oder [german.about.com](http://german.about.com/library/blvoc_gerloan.htm)

Comment: Sprachen besitzt man nicht, man spricht sie. (Die Sprachen gehören dir nicht, sie sind nicht dein Eigentum. Du verwendest sie). Du besitzt also nicht zwei Muttersprachen, sondern du sprichst zwei Muttersprachen

Comment: Alle Probleme, die der Wunsch mit sich bringen kann, wird durch diese [Rede im sächsischen Landtag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAemDwDAZno) auf den Punkt gebracht.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wie kann man ihnen entgehen?

**Gar nicht.** Selbst wenn du nur deutsche Wörter verwendest, die anderen werden ja immer noch die Fremdwörter verwenden, also ganz drum herum kommst du eh nicht.

Trotzalledem gibt es für fast alles tatsächlich ein deutsches Wort. Der Haken an der Sache ist, dass die meisten den deutschen Begriff **nicht** kennen oder gar verstehen. Kürzlichst wurde in einer anderen Frage CPU als Beispiel genannt. Wer mit der Materie bewandert ist, wird *zentrale Recheneinheit* wahrscheinlich noch verstehen. "Außenstehende" aber eher nicht. Aber immerhin gäbe es hier noch das Wort *Prozessor*.

Insofern wird es aber generell schwer, die fremdsprachlichen Wörter zu umgehen. Verwendest du die deutschen Wörter, wirst du also möglicherweise nicht verstanden. Aber selbst wenn man dich versteht, wird man dich zumindest schräg anschauen, warum du so komische Wörter verwendest.

Wenn du dennoch solche Wörter suchen möchtest, so hilft dir ein jedes Wörterbuch bei vielen Begriffen. Aber auch die Wikipediaartikel nennen oft mehrere mögliche Ausdrücke oder zumindest eine präzise Umschreibung.

PS: Ein Smartphone kannst du "Handy" nennen. Das sieht zwar Englisch aus, wird aber kein Engländer verstehen. Und dann gibt's da natürlich auch den Begriff [Mobiltelefon](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobiltelefon). (Wobei weder *Mobil* noch *Telefon* germanischen Ursprungs sind.)

Comment: Wenn man schon vom Smartphone zum Handy verallgemeinert, kann man ja auch vollends vom Handy zum Telefon verallgemeinern.

Comment: Könnte man, wenn es diese kabelgebundenen Fernsprecher nicht doch noch vereinzelt gäbe ...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Jupp, oder eher Mobiltelefon. Hab's noch in die Antwort aufgenommen. Danke.

Comment: @Ingmar: Es gibt eben auch die kabellosen, aber nicht ganz so schlauen Mobiltelefone noch immer.

Answer (score 6):

So ist Sprache eben, man nimmt Wörter aus anderen Sprachen und integriert sie mehr oder weniger problemlos in die eigene, bis man ihnen unter Umständen die Herkunft gar nicht mehr ansieht (Keks, z. B.). Das machen alle Sprachen der Welt so, ausnahmslos (wenn nicht aus politischen Gründen aktiv dagegen gesteuert wird). Früher waren oft das Griechische und Lateinische, später sehr oft das Französische Quell dieser "neuen" Wörter; heute ist es eben Englisch.

Sich dagegen wehren zu wollen ist in der Regel ein Kampf gegen Windmühlen. Manchen ([Philipp von Zesen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philipp_von_Zesen)) ist es zum Teil geglückt, aber nicht sehr oft. Viele Modeworte fallen auch von selbst wieder aus der Verwendung, ansonsten wird irgendwann die Schreibweise und Aussprache germanisiert und die Übernahme ist abgeschlossen. Solche Wörter werden dann auch nicht mehr als Lehn- oder Fremdwörter betrachtet.

*Als Beispiel soll Computer, Software und Smartphone genannt werden.*

Natürlich kann man *Rechner* und *Programm* sagen, aber soll man das? Für Smartphone gibt es überhaupt keine Eindeutschung, die nicht lächerlich klänge: nachdem aber zunehmend keine anderen Telephone mehr in Verwendung sind, böte sich einfach *Telephon* oder, klar, *Handy* an.

*Und nicht nur das: oft klingt es in meinen Ohren so, als ob Jemand versuche Englisch zu sprechen - doch dies nicht sonderlich gut kann und deshalb deutsche Wörter nutzen muss.*

Es gibt diesen Trend natürlich: gerade in Werbung und Marketing werden oft ohne Not englische Wörter (oftmals auch falsch) verwendet, obwohl es dafür gute deutsche Ausdrücke gäbe: *CityCall*, *Coffee to go* u. s. w. Manchmal erfinden wir auch "englische" Wörter, die es im Original gar nicht gibt: *Handy* wurde schon genannt, spontan fallen mir noch *Beamer* oder *Talkmaster* ein. Viele dieser Wörter sind auch schon wieder auf dem Rückzug (*Twen*, *Pullunder*, *Dressman*, ...).

*Ich finde es schade, dass man im Deutschen nicht eigene Wörter erstellt, wie man es auch im Französischen tut.*

Naja. In Frankreich wacht die *Académie française* über die "Reinheit" der französische Sprache und schlägt regelmäßig französisierte Alternativen zu (in der Regel) englischen Fremdwörtern vor, die in der Praxis mehr oder weniger gut angenommen werden. Eigentlich ist das kein Modell, das ich mir für den deutschen Sprachraum wünsche. Es würde natürlich, da deutsch bekanntlich eine plurizentristische Sprache ist, schon an einer zentralen Sprachenautorität scheitern ...

Comment: "spontan fallen mir noch Beamer oder Talkmaster ein" - wobei anzumerken wäre, dass es interessanterweise gerade für diese zwei auch im Englischen nicht unbedingt (ohne Kontext) eindeutige Begriffe gibt.

Comment: Ich sage "Programm" zu einem Programm und "Software" zu Software. Einen Computer nenne ich nach Belieben "Computer" oder "Rechner".

Comment: +1, aber Französisch wird auch nicht nur in Frankreich gesprochen, das Argument aus Deinem letzten Absatz ist daher kein starkes.

Comment: Tatsache ist, dass es keine "Deutsche Akademie" gibt, und daran wird sich in absehbarer Zeit wohl auch nichts ändern ...

Comment: @Ingmar, yep, aber wenn die KMK oder wer auch immer eine einsetzen wollte, würden die Deutchschweizer sie ebensowenig daran hindern wie die Frankokanadier den Franzosen ein Hindernis waren.

Answer (score 4):

Es ist eine allgemeine Erscheinung, dass Sprachen sich gegenseitig beeinflussen und von Nachbarsprachen Wortschatz übernehmen. Latein hat von Griechisch übernommen, Deutsch von Latein und Französisch, und Englisch von Latein und Französisch und vielen anderen Sprachen. Wer heute meint, er müsste Computer oder Telefon durch etwas Deutsches ersetzen, schwimmt gegen den Strom. Übrigens ist Computer zwar aus dem Englichen übernommen, es ist aber letztlich eine Ableitung von lateinisch computare.

Bei der Unzahl von Dingen, für die wir Wörter brauchen, kommt keine Sprache nur mit eigenen Wörtern aus oder jedes Wort hätte zehn Bedeutungen. Computer ist eindeutig und präzise, Rechner ist schon mehrdeutig, das kann auch eine einfache Rechenmaschine oder sogar eine Person sein.

Purismus aus Prinzip ist weltfremd, allerdings sollte die eigene Sprache auch nicht mit unnötigem Fremdwortschatz überlastet sein.  Es ist also in jedem Einzelfall abzuwägen, ob das Fremdwort ein Zugewinn ist oder unnötig und leicht mit einem eigenen Wort ersetzt werden kann. Das entscheiden die Sprecher im Laufe der Zeit aber meist selbst.

So hat die Post versucht, Telefon durch Fernsprecher zu ersetzen, die Leute haben aber das deutsche Wort nicht übernommen. Und es ist gar nicht so einfach, so etwas zu begründen.

Etwas ganz anderes sind neue technische Bereiche wie Computer-Bereich, Internet oder Ähnliches. Hier ist Englisch führend und in Übersetzungen wird nicht lange nach brauchbaren Übersetzungen gesucht, sondern einfach das englische Wort übernommen. Oft ist das wirklich ein furchtbares Kauderwelsch. Aber es dauert immer eine Zeit bis man einen klaren, systematischen deutschen Begriff für etwas Nichtssagendes im Englischen gefunden hat. So musste ich mir lange überlegen, was ich für das blöde URĹ sagen könnte. Uniform Resource Locator sagt ja nichts Gescheites. Ich sage heute einfach Internet-Adresse oder Webadresse, dann weiß man, was gemeint ist. Aber es ist ein langerer Prozess bis man von nichtssagendem Fachchinesisch zu klaren systematischen Begriffen kommt.

Es gibt auch den umgekehrten Fall, wie im Bereich der Automobiltechnik, wo Deutsch führend ist und wo auch Fachleute in Amerika nur die deutschen Begriffe verwenden, weil es eben dauert bis man Ausländisches vernünftig in die eigene Sprache integriert.

Comment: Hast Du ein Beispiel für deutsche Begriffe in der Automobiltechnik, die in Amerika verwendet werden?

Comment: Ich habe  das vor einiger Zeit  irgendwo gelesen. Habe aber das Gefühl, das werde ich nicht mehr finden. Nehme an, dass es sich da um neue Technologien im elektronischen Bereich handelt.

Comment: Und ich nehme an, dass das Quatsch ist ;=

Comment: Deine Meinung. Mir kam das, was ich gelesen habe keineswegs als Quatsch vor, und dafür habe ich schon ein Gefühl. Ich weiß nur nicht mehr um welche innovativen Technologien der Autoindustrie es ging, vielleicht war es  der Sektor Wasserstoff-Auto oder so was.

Comment: Of course, I didn't find the article I had in mind, but something similar  http://www.gtai.de/GTAI/Navigation/EN/Invest/Industries/Mobility/automotive.html

Comment: Ich habe da nichts zur Terminologie in der Automobilbranche gefunden.

Comment: Schon richtig. Aber die Graphick zeigt dass Deutschland das Land mit der größten Innovation ist und in innovativen Bereichen wird direTerminologie erstmal von anderen übernommen.

Comment: "In innovativen Bereichen wird direTerminologie erstmal von anderen übernommen": eben dies bezweifle ich in diesem Fall. Dass dies historisch in der Wissenschaft der Fall war, ist mir bekannt.

Answer (score 1):

Für die ersten zwei finde ich problemlos "Rechner" und "Programm" bei dict.leo.org . Für Smartphone würde ich nur eine Umschreibung bilden können, wie "Kleinstrechner mit Telefon- und Fotofunktion" die viele nicht verstehen würden.

Spätestens hier wird es leicht zwanghaft, aber in geschriebener Sprache hat man meist die Zeit eine deutsche Formulierung zu finden, die aber vielleicht französichen oder lateinischen Ursprungs ist, um frühere, starke Spracheinflüsse zu benennen. Neben dict.leo.org sollte aber jedes Englisch-Deutsch-Wörterbuch gute Dienste leisten.

Answer (score 1):

Anglizismen im Deutschen zu entgehen geht nicht, und ich halte den Versuch, Anglizismen entkommen zu wollen, auch für ein bisschen eigenbrötlerisch. Warum sollte man den französischen Weg gehen, und krampfhaft ein neues Wort erfinden, wenn es dafür schon ein Wort gibt, noch dazu, wenn das neu erfundene Wort im Ausland nicht auf Anhieb verstanden wird?

Ich will anhand der Anglizismen aus deiner Frage versuchen, Deutsche Ersatzbegriffe zu finden:

> Computer = Rechner

Tatsächlich ist das Wort »Rechner« auch als Synonym für »Computer« in Gebrauch, und es wird auch richtig verstanden. Aber »Computer« ist gar kein echter Anglizismus. Es ist ein lateinisches Wort, das von *computare* (*berechnen*) abgeleitet ist. Auch das - von vielen als deutsch empfundene - Wort *Konto* geht auf das lateinische *computare* zurück. Während aber der *Computer* einen Umweg durch die englische Sprache genommen hat, hat das *Konto* seinen Weg über die Italienische Sprache ins Deutsche gefunden.

---

> 1. Software = weiche Ware, weiches Gerät
> 2. Software = Programme

Die erste Übersetzung versucht, den Begriff wörtlich zu übersetzten und führt zu einem völlig unbrauchbaren Ergebnis, weil diese Begriffe nicht verstanden werden.

Der zweite Versuch kommt der Sache inhaltlich schon näher, hat aber den Nachteil, einen Anglizismus durch einen anderen zu ersetzen.

Das **Programm**, in der hier verwendeten Bedeutung, kann nämlich selbst als Anglizismus aufgefasst werden, nämlich in demselben Sinne, wie »*Computer*« vielen als Anglizismus gilt. Das Wort *Programm* als Liste von Befehlen, die die zentrale Recheneinheit eines Computers ausführen soll, stammt vom englischen Verb *to programme* ab. Dieses wiederum ist der Altgriechischen Sprache entlehnt. Eine griechische *prógramma* ist eine schriftliche Bekanntmachung, oder eine Tagesordnung, also etwas, das ebenfalls Punkt für Punkt abgearbeitet wird. Auch das Fernseh-Programm hat seinen Ursprung in diesem Wort, und natürlich auch das Partei-Programm, wobei bei letzterem die Reihenfolge, in der die Punkte beachtet werden sollen, irrelevant ist.

Man könnte daher das *Programm* durch das deutsche Wort »*Befehlsliste*« ersetzen:

> Software = Befehlslisten

Das wird aber niemand verstehen.

---

> Smartphone = kluges Fernsprechgerät

Das ist nicht nur ziemlich holprig (weil es aus einem Wort zwei Wörter macht), sonder weckt durch das Wort "klug" Erwartungen, die das Gerät nicht erfüllen kann, denn das englische »*smart*« bedeutet nicht zu genau 100% dasselbe wie das deutsche »*klug*«, aber ein besseres deutsches Wort gibt es dafür nun mal nicht.

Alle anderen alternativen Übersetzungen enthalten selbst wieder Wortbestandteile, die keine deutschen Wörter sind.

---

Aber ich möchte auch eine Gegenfrage stellen: Warum stören dich gerade englische Wörter in der Deutschen Sprache? Was ist mit diesen Wörtern?

> Amateur, Bonbonniere, Chef, Depot, Etage, Fassade, Garage, Hotel ...

Das sind lauter französische Wörter, die ins Deutsche importiert wurden. Findest du auch, die sollte man durch deutsche Wörter ersetzen?

Oder umgekehrt: Deutsche Wörter, die Eingang in die Französische Sprache gefunden haben:

> le doppelgänger, la gemütlichkeit, le glockenspiel, le leitmotiv, le minnesang, le poltergeist, le rollmops, le schnaps, le waldsterben, le weltanschauung, le zuckerwatte

Vielleicht wollte man auch die Französische Sprache von diesen Germanismen befreien?

Comment: Dass die Wörter im Ausland nicht auf Anhieb verstanden würden, ist wohl kaum ein Argument, da auch die deutsche Sprache an sich von vielen nicht verstanden wird. Die Unterscheidung von echten und unechten Anglizismen erschließt sich mir auch nicht. Und dass Dir untaugliche Eindeutschungen einfallen, ist kein Argument dafür, dass es keine tauglichen gibt. Andererseits: +1 für das A bis H französischer Lehnwörter.